# How to loop id of the text field in the table using JavaScript in the project asp.net 6 MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am looking for anyone who can assist me on this issue I am facing. I am looking for how to loop the ids I set in my table body on input fields where I have to choose item from the selection options then to populate the data calculated to fill two other input text fields using id in the JavaScript. The issue is I can get the data filled to the input fields but only on the first row when I add the second row it changes the data in the same first row. See the attachments.

```
<table class="table table-hover MyTable table-bordered" id="MyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:19%;">
                Product Code
            </th>                                                                                                                                                                                              
            <th style="width:24%;">
                Product Name
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%;">
                Quantity
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%;">
                Price
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%;">
                Amount
            </th>
            <th style="width:12%;">
                <button id='btnAddDetailRow' type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary visible" onclick="AddItem()">
                    Add
                </button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.InvoiceDetails.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width:19%;">
                    <select asp-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].ProductId" id="lstProduct" class="form-control Product" asp-items="@ViewBag.Products" onchange=" getProductName(this); getPrice(this); changeData(this);"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width:24%;">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Product" id="txtProductName" class="form-control form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Product" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width:15%;">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Quantity" class="form-control QtyTotal" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width:15%;">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Price" id="txtPrice" class="form-control form-control-plaintext PriceTotal" readonly />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width:15%;">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].IsDeleted" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Amount" class="form-control form-control-plaintext AmountTotal" readonly />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.InvoiceDetails[i].Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width:12%;">
                    <button id='btnremove-@i' type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger visible" onclick="DeleteItem(this)">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getPrice(productId) {

            var lstbox = document.getElementById('dropdownPrice');

            var txtPrice = document.getElementById('txtPrice');

            var items = lstbox.options;

            for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (items[i].value == productId.value) {
                    txtPrice.value = items[i].text;
                    return;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        function getProductName(productId) {

            var lstbox = document.getElementById('dropdownProductName');

            var txtProductName = document.getElementById('txtProductName');

            var items = lstbox.options;


            for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (items[i].value == productId.value) {
                    txtProductName.value = items[i].text;
                    return;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        function AddItem(btn) {

            var table;
            table = document.getElementById('MyTable');
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length - 1].outerHTML;

            var lastrowIdx = rows.length - 2;

            var nextrowIdx = eval(lastrowIdx) + 1;

            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('_' + lastrowIdx + '_', '_' + nextrowIdx + '_');
            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('[' + lastrowIdx + ']', '[' + nextrowIdx + ']');
           rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('-' + lastrowIdx, '-' + nextrowIdx);

           var newRow = table.insertRow();
           newRow.innerHTML = rowOuterHtml;

           var x = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

           for (var cnt = 0; cnt < x.length; cnt++) {
               if (x[cnt].type == "text" && x[cnt].id.indexOf('_' + nextrowIdx + '_') > 0) {
               if (x[cnt].id.indexOf('Unit') == 0)
                   x[cnt].value = '';
               }
               else if (x[cnt].type == "number" && 
                   x[cnt].id.indexOf('_' + nextrowIdx + '_') > 0)
                       x[cnt].value = 0;
               }

       }
    </script>
}
```

attached video [Problem presentation](https://screenrec.com/share/bzMuw8KhSW)

Comment: Could you share your code about how to dynamic add the row?

Comment: The id is unique, you need to set the ids for the product name and price.

Comment: @QingGuo The code added above. Thanks

Comment: @QingGuo yes, the Id is unique as you can see in the code however what am looking for, is how I can iterate them with the loop cause when I inspect the output I see the Ids are there in the second row but since it needed to have the position to refer where they can set is where I think it fails and set again in the first row.